# SaveFileDialog get Path selected

Tags: c#, silverlight

i use c# silverlight ! 
I don't find how to get the "path" selected from an SaveFileDialog can someone help ?

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.DefaultFileName = fileName;
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Pdf files (*.Pdf)|*.Pdf";
saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";

if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
  string path = "";// find a way to get path selected
}
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `FileName` property of the dialog.

Comment: Did you notice the Silverlight tag?

Comment: I have try 

string fileName= saveFileDialog.SafeFileName;
string Path = saveFileDialog.File.DirectoryName;
But I can't acces to File

Comment: It seems you can't get the full path for security reasons. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog.safefilename%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use the `SelectedPath` property of the dialog

Comment: Did you notice the Silverlight tag?